# How can i search an JSON array in lambda with python and get a response in AWS API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Homework question here (sorry)
I've asked my prof twice and only get vague answers and the learning material doesn't show you what they ask for on the homework... I have searched here and on google and I get close once in a while but never there. But its also because I'm new with python.

Here is what I have to do.
This is all happening in AWS lambda and AWS API gateway
I have to make an array in the configured events, in JSON.
I have to search the array using python for the queried sport and team from the API.
Then the browser has to show the response with the data from the array.

This is the simple JSON array I made

```
 {
  "Records": [
      {
          "Sport":"basketball",
          "Team": "bulls",
          "Scores": {
              "Score1": "222",
              "Score2": "333",
              "Score3": "444"
                  }
              },
              {
          "Sport":"basketball",
          "Team": "cults",
          "Scores": {
              "Score1": "222",
              "Score2": "333",
              "Score3": "444"
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
```

And I know there is not much here, but here is my python. I used a for loop to at least show some data.

```
import JSON



def lambda_handler (event, context):

    print('This sucks balls')
    for index in event['Records']:

            return index
```

And this is what I have in the API Gateway, in the GET Integration Request

```
{
    "Records": "input.params('Records')"

}
```

I am probably 1000% overthinking this. but i have not been this stuck for a while....

Comment: You haven't mentioned what errors you are getting or what your getting stuck on. If its just reading the json, you may need to do json.dumps(event['Records']) to read the json array.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response. This code will respond with the full entirety of the json.  In the API response i only get the response of "i" when i query sport=basketball in the api My full problem is i do not know where to go now.  json.dumps(event['Records']) just gives me null.

Comment: oh so your problem is that its just returning the singular key:value instead of the element array?

Comment: partially yeah. 
So lets say i query https://amazonaws.com/try1?Sport=baseball&team=Cubs  Then it would respond with a list of the last 5 games scores.  So i want to use json for the array that this query would search through. Then if the sport to team is NOT found in the subset, then it would respond with a 500, saying to request a specific team or sport.
If you want i can PM you the paper i am reading from. As i may not be explaining it well.  Btw, thank you for the help.

Comment: No worries, and potentially PM me the paper. Let me see if i got the issue / outcome straight first. 

Currently your 'return index' is giving back event['Records'][index] right? and you want it to instead to just return the scores from the query? e.g. return index['Scores']

Comment: Not sure how to send a PM on here. i don't think we can. but here is the paper.
http://blazingfire.com/Homework3.pdf
in the return index it returns

Response:
{
  "Sport": "basketball",
  "Team": "bulls",
  "Scores": {
    "Score1": 222,
    "Score2": 333,
    "Score3": 444
  }
}

This is only one part of the array of course.

Comment: and in the API

Request: /
Status: 200
Latency: 21 ms
Response Body
{
  "errorMessage": "Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)",
  "errorType": "JSONDecodeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
      354,
      "loads",
      "return _default_decoder.decode(s)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
      342,
      "decode",
      "raise JSONDecodeError(\"Extra data\", s, end)"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: My friend, did you disappear? lol

Comment: Sorry went to bed, on your return index, try instead: return {"body": json.dumps(index, separators=(',', ':'))}   That should at least get a response from your apigateway. also do a print index to see what your actually returning.

Comment: Hey not a problem :) We all need that good rest!
So i printed the index and this is the response.
    "code" Response:
null

Request ID:
"ef893a3c-4246-4d87-a4a2-13856621c5ed"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: ef893a3c-4246-4d87-a4a2-13856621c5ed Version: $LATEST
This sucks balls
{'Sport': 'basketball', 'Team': 'bulls', 'Scores': {'Score1': 222, 'Score2': 333, 'Score3': 444}}
{'Sport': 'basketball', 'Team': 'cults', 'Scores': {'Score1': 222, 'Score2': 3343, 'Score3': 4444}}
END RequestId: ef893a3c-4246-4d87-a4a2-13856621c5ed }

Comment: i changed the API as suggested and got

{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'json\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{\"body\": json.dumps(index, separators=(\',\', \':\'))}\"; line: 1, column: 15]"}

But in the code in lambda i  made it back to return index and it at least pulled the first array from the array  lol

Comment: Change your import statement to lowercase json, to match the function call json.dumps

Comment: i did earlier. just never edited the beginning lol
Btw thank you for working on this with me :D

I got a good response from the program:
Response:
{
  "body": "{\"Sport\":\"basketball\",\"Team\":\"bulls\",\"Scores\":{\"Score1\":222,\"Score2\":333,\"Score3\":444}}"
}

From the API  from the link like this
amazonaws.com/try10?Sports=basketball&Teams=bulls

{"body": "\"i\""}
Thats good! i think, its seeing things. Now how can i take that API input, put it in to the lambda, search the json array and return the scores haha.